# Can I use roaring bitmap for lucence inverted index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, solar

We've more than 5 billion documents that needs to be indexed for full text search. All of these documents are static and never needs to be changed.

After a lot of research we found that using roaring bitmaps with Redis to build an inverted index is super fast with minimal resources.

The question now, Can we use roaring bitmaps in lucene inverted index?

Comment: i mean, what specifically you want to do with those bitmaps in lucene?

Comment: @Mysterion speeding up the search speed, using minimal computing power.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has used Roaring bitmaps by default for years. It was added in 2014 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5983

Elias Fano was removed in 2015. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6484

Comment: does lucene post evaluation of a filter caches the result as in filter cache ?

Comment: is it possible to get the result in the form of roaringbitmap  , i assume lucene internally is storing the posting list using roaring bitmaps then executes the filters using this bitmap and the final result (gets cached in filter cache) and decompressed to point to actual document sets , i am wondering if one can access this final bitmap directly ?

Answer (score 0):

Idea of using roaring bit maps was already evaluated in Lucene world. You could take a look at full results here - http://people.apache.org/~jpountz/doc_id_sets4.html

General idea is, that though roaring bitmaps are efficient, it could be used only in 2 features:

- Iterating over all matching documents (which could be the case if you run constant score query)
- Advancing to the first doc id contained in the set, this is typically used in intersection between filter and query

All in all, I think currently Lucene using [Elias-Fano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano%E2%80%93Elias_coding) encoding in most of the cases, which is measured to be faster. Also this means, that you could just use Lucene and be confident, that it have great speed in building inverted index and processing the queries